# List data member in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have written WCF service which has `List<String>` as data member. I am adding data to the list in my `service.svc` but I am not finding any data in my list. Here is my data contract class.

```
[datacontract]
public class CompositeType
    {
        //here are data members
        public List<String> strlist ;
        [DataMember]
        public List<String> StrList
        {
            get { return strlist; }
            set { strlist = value; }

        }
    }
```

in my service.svc

```
public void myservice(CompositeType com)
{
 comtype.StrList.add("abc");
 System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\\for1.txt", comType.StrList[0]);
}
```

But no data is found in that file. Please help me. I searched a lot but could not trace what's wrong in that list member.

And I used this service in my other app.

Comment: in your method `myservice` you are using `comtype` and not the parameter `com` - also `List<T>`doesn't have an `add` method

Comment: List<T> does have add method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ComType is my mistake.. what is the alternative solution to ADD list of strings.?

Comment: well C# is case sensitive.. `list.Add(..)` exists, but `list.add(..)`does not. When you show code on SO, make sure it compiles :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to mark the backing field as DataMember and not the property:

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<String> strlist ;

        public List<String> StrList
        {
            get { return strlist; }
            set { strlist = value; }

        }
    }
```

// With list

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<String> strlist = new List<String>();

        public List<String> StrList
        {
            get { return strlist; }
            set { strlist = value; }

        }
    }
```

Comment: am facing error as null point exception is unhandled by the user code.. I tried by changing [DataMember] public List<String> strlist = new List<String>(); but still my exception was solved..please help me..

Comment: In the question you wrote that there was no data in the file, now you are talking of a NullRefException. Big difference! :) Please post more details about the exception. Also you can initialize the strlist. I updated my post.